# Not exporting column name's to excel correctly from dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to export the data from dataGridView to excel. It works well, but I can't export the column name's correctly. The problem is that the column name should be: `id` and it is `idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn` . And the other problem is that the first entry from the db is not exported. I mean, instead of my first entry in the db it puts the column names, and then, it puts only the 2nd entry, then the 3rd, so on. Thanks !

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var connString = (@"Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\Angajati.sdf");
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "SELECT * FROM info ";
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Int16 i, j;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            //adds column names to excel
            string[] colNames = new string[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            int col = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
                colNames[col++] = dc.Name;

            char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1);

            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment
                        = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag\db.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes");
        }



        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the column name issue,

replace this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
    colNames[col++] = dc.Name;
```

with this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
    colNames[col++] = dc.HeaderText;
```

**UPDATE**: For the first missing row, make this change:

```
        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                //xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works like charm this way. The only problem left is that it didn't get the first entry in the database, only the second,because the first is replaced with the column names. Why?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find out, *where* the problem occurs:

1. getting the Data from the GridView
2. sending the data to excel

Use a debuger, set breakpoints and inspect the intermediate values like `dataTable` and `colNames`